# Matlab Code for a GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-gui

Write a function with the header

```
function [newX] = myPhotoNegative(X)
```

where X is a 3-dimensional matrix containing double values between 0 and 1

where

> X(:,:,1) are the red levels
>
> X(:,:,2) are the green levels
>
> X(:,:,3) are the blue levels

This function will switch each channel level with its complement.

**For example,**

```
if X(10,20,1) had a value of 0.35, it will become 0.65

if X(10,20,2) had a value of 0.9, it will become 0.1

if X(10,20,3) had a value of 0.2, it will become 0.8
```

Comment: Consider accepting an answer or upvoting in case it helped. That is how SO works

Answer (score 1):

simply do 1-val for every single entry `val` in the matrix?

```
function newX = myPhotoNegative(X)
   newX = 1-X;
end
```